# how to get definitely rid of this apn_on_rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rubygems, generator

I installed this gem and ran `rails g apn_migrations`

I don't need the gem anymore, I removed it form my gemfile, from my rakefile, deleted from my migrations, from schema.rb and ran `rake db:schema:load`

A search on my workspace shows no occurence of the string "apn" anymore, but the tables created by the original `rails g apn_migrations` still appear, I don't know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't run your migrations again, then your schema.rb file is probably still the same as it was before. I'm assuming that this is a dev environment, and you can just blow away your database and rerun your migrations. If you've already released this to production, then add a new migration which gets rid of your unwanted tables.